# Why are many Android API classes non-final, even though they are not explicitly documented for inheritance?

Tags: android, effective-java

Effective Java (Joshua Bloch) Item 17 says :

> "Design and Document or inheritance or else prohibit it"

However, just a cursory glance through the Android APIs reveals that most of the API classes are non-final; which is OK if they are also documented for inheritance (`View` of `Activity`, for example). But there are also several non-final classes, but the documentation makes no mention about the inheritability of these classes. Just some arbitrary examples to illustrate my point:

- The classes representing the System Services (`WifiManager`, `NotificationManager` ...)
- Utility classes like `UriMatcher`.
- Some hardware-specific classes like `Camera`.

Openness and extensibility being the philosophy of Android, is the convention reversed here? Meaning, could one assume that ***all*** of the Android API classes are designed to be inherited (whether explicitly documented or otherwise); unless declared final?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my €0,02: Clean OO design by the book is one thing, making things work for *all* possible use cases in practice is another. The principles of clean OO design sometimes are somewhat of academic nature. - And maybe a little bit of black and white.

Think for instance about *who* uses the Android API provided by google: It's not only app developers but also device manufacturers who *need* to specialize general APIs for their devices.

So, for me, SW design is neither black nor white in most cases; the shades of grey are important.

And finally: In practice I have seldom (read: *never*) seen problems caused by "carelessly" omitted `final` keywords (on classes), while unreflected overuse of `final` (often caused by thoughts like "my code is *sooo* [great | ugly], no one will actually *ever want* to modify it through inheritance") can be quite a pain.

"I know that I know nothing" seems to fit here: It is presumptuous to claim that one knows *all* the crazy, ingenious, creative, smart,... ideas of others for how one's code may be used in the future beforehand.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the device manufacturers themselves needing to sub-class the API classes! Further, I see your point regarding the "better leave it open then close out all avenues" philosophy. Awarding this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Android developers went to great lengths to ensure that extensibility, while not recommended in many cases, is possible.  The motivation behind this appears to be related to testing environments.

For instance, it would be much more difficult to create a faux `WifiManager` for the purposes of creating unit tests if it were finalized.  Without the finalization, it is trivial to subclass the `WifiManager` (e.g. to mimic "unexpected" wifi disconnection during operation) and return an instance of this subclass from a customized testing `Context`.

So while you will probably never find a reason to implement a subclass of the these classes in an application that you ship to the end users, the flexibility is there to allow you to extend them if it is necessary for one reason or another.

In the case of utility classes, the answer is simply that the utility of the class is not diminished by allowing the developer to subclass; in many cases, a developer can achieve more understandable code reuse by inheritance than by aggregation and delegation.

Comment: I liked this answer too. Unfortunately, I cannot mark 2 answer as "Accepted", but you definitely got my upvote.